# Need to know what projectuid equates to in useralldata table

Tags: project-server

I need to find out which project/site my custom list is referring to when I look at the useralldata that contains the custom list data in the project_server_content_01 database.

Comment: I think the only advise you are going to get is "You should not be querying the content databases directly"

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is look at the projects table, find a project name that I know is in only one of the PWA sites.  Then, I know what the GUID is from then on in all tables for that site.